# ArrayList<Number> is not applicable for the arguments (int)

Tags: java

This is my code which is shown as follows:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.math.*;
public class Exercise {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        ArrayList<Number> list = new ArrayList<>();

         list.add(59);    
        list.add(47);
        list.add(32);
        list.add(43);
        list.add(95);
        list.add(36);
  }

    public static void sort(ArrayList<Number> list){
        int iteration = list.size();

        while (iteration >= 0){
            for (int i = 0; i < list.size() - 1; i++){
                for (int k = 1; k < list.size(); k++){

                    if (list.get(i).getValue() > list.get(k).getValue()){
                        Number temp = list.get(k);
                        list.set(k, list.get(i));
                        list.set(i, temp);
                    }
                }
            }

        iteration --;
    }
 }

}
class Number{
    double d;
    Number(double d){
        this.d = d;
    }

    double getValue(){
        return d;
    }
}
```

The error message is:

The method add(int, Number) in the type ArrayList is not applicable for the arguments (int)

The error corresponds from this part:

```
 list.add(59);    
        list.add(47);
        list.add(32);
        list.add(43);
        list.add(95);
        list.add(36);
```

Can anyone give me a help for fixing the error? Thank you!

Comment: it needs a `Number`. `59` is not a `Number`, it's an `int`.

Comment: @askquestion depends on what you want to achieve. For the moment you're trying to reinvent the wheel. Why are you creating a `Number`?

Comment: @Adelin, The code is written based on the original question, which requires to use Number.

Comment: Why not just use `List<Integer>`?  That would seem to make the most sense to me.  When speaking of `List<Number>`, you can't really do any math with such a list because you don't know which type of number is being contained inside the collection.

Comment: Bad habit to create classes with the same name as `java.lang` classes

Comment: This is why you should avoid using classes with the same names as standard JDK classes.  If this were `java.lang.Number`, the `add` would have worked.  Because it's your own `Number`, it will not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arraylist you are using is holding Number types. You need to store number objects in your list instead of integers.

Example :

```
ArrayList<Number> list = new ArrayList<>();
Number num = new Number(12.0);
list.add(num);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. In your `ArrayList<Number>` you have to add instances of `Number` not `int`.
2. Since your `Number` constructor expects `double` not `int` you have to fill it like:

   ```
   list.add(new Number(59.0));
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You are not adding **Number** class actually, instead you are trying to add **Integer**.

Try this

```
    list.add(new Number(59));    
    list.add(new Number(47));
    list.add(new Number(32));
    list.add(new Number(43));
    list.add(new Number(95));
    list.add(new Number(36));
```